# ldahist function in R error

Tags: r

I am trying to plot the `ldahist` object from R, but I keep getting an error message:

`Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large`

Here is my code:

```
x = lda(xxx ~ x1+x2+x3+x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8+x9+x10+x11+x12, data =dat)
ldahist(data=x, g=xxx, nbins = 2, h=10,x0 = - 10/1000,xlim = range(20), ymax = 100,
        type = c("histogram"),
        col = 5)
```

Can anybody please explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, if you are trying to run the code in RStudio, you'll need to either make the plotting window larger. Also, I have two other alternatives:

Option 1. Use `pdf` and/or `png` functions to see if you can direct the image to be saved to your local machine, such as the "Downloads" or "Desktop" directories. Make sure to run `dev.off()` after running the `pdf`/`png` functions! Check the help file if necessary

Option 2. Change the `par` setting. The default is `mar=c(5,4,4,2)`. You might want to make the margins smaller. Check details by running `?par` (it's a very long, but detailed, help file).